# GoogleTV Mediaplayer cannot handle http datasource with Transfer-Encoding : chunked

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer, google-tv

I am trying to play a raw liveTV mpeg2_ts stream via google tv Media player;
The stream is unbounded (live tv) so there is no content-length.
The stream is accessed via a url that looks like this http:///livetv?channum=X

This was tested with VLC has a client and worked great. However using GTV is another story

The stream response header contains the header Tranfer-Encoding : chunked.
Attempting to play that stream in GTV media player causes the following error :

I/AVAPIMediaPlayer(142): Found HTTP success.  Connection is HTTP/1.1, code was 206 
I/AVAPIMediaPlayer(142): Found content type video/mpeg 
W/AVAPIMediaPlayer(142): Error, reached end of headers before finding required fields.

Looking at this file: [gtv_curl_transfer_engine.cpp](https://code.google.com/p/googletv-mirrored-source/source/browse/tv/frameworks/libs/avapi_mediaplayer/http_source/gtv_curl_transfer_engine.cpp?repo=vendor) it seems that v3 has removed the support for Transfer-Encoding and only supports / requires a Content-Length.

the previous version of the same file ([GTV v2 gtv_curl_transfer_engine.cpp](https://code.google.com/p/googletv-mirrored-source/source/browse/tv/frameworks/libs/avapi_mediaplayer/http_source/gtv_curl_transfer_engine.cpp?repo=vendor&r=b5ba2dc7eef0afefa66cade0d837442675ba8066)) supported it but it was removed in the current version.

what was the rationale to remove the support ? and how would one work around it ?

I was thinking about a set of temp files and chaining mediaplayer instances for playback but I would rather limit file system interactions given the nature of the stream...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my interactions with google, there is no plan to change this behavior.
The course of action is to provide the videos in a HTTP Live stream format (m3u8)